# Using data class with strings

Tags: python, oop, module, package

I'm simplifying a project, so it's my first time splitting an entire script in modules/packages so I have the following class:

```
class Decorators:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    decorator = r'''
                  />
     (           //-------------------------------------(
    (*)OXOXOXOXO(*>======================================\
     (           \\---------------------------------------)
                  \>
    '''

    special_decorator = r'''
                             .
                         /   ))     |\         )               ).
                   c--. (\  ( `.    / )  (\   ( `.     ).     ( (
                   | |   ))  ) )   ( (   `.`.  ) )    ( (      ) )
                   | |  ( ( / _..----.._  ) | ( ( _..----.._  ( (
     ,-.           | |---) V.'-------.. `-. )-/.-' ..------ `--) \._
     | /===========| |  (   |      ) ( ``-.`\/'.-''           (   ) ``-._
     | | / / / / / | |--------------------->  <-------------------------_>=-
     | \===========| |                 ..-'./\.`-..                _,,-'
     `-'           | |-------._------''_.-'----`-._``------_.-----'
                   | |         ``----''            ``----''
                   | |
                   c--`

    '''
```

I want to know how can I call the strings from this class to print it out on the main function for example:

```
import decorators

def main():
   print(decorators.special_decorator)
```

I want it to print the string that I'm calling from the module

Comment: Did you mean: `print(decorators.Decorators.special_decorator) `?

Comment: Correct! that is the correct syntax to call those strings from the class

Comment: btw in python you only really call functions (and callables) and with other objects you access them.